# Passing a method of self to decorator as an argument

Tags: python, function, decorator, python-decorators

I have a class A, which has a lot of old complex methods, that I have re-written.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1

    def old_func(self):
        return 2

    @property
    def b(self):
        if not hasattr(self, 'b'):
            self._b = B(self)
        return _b

class B:
    def __init__(self, a: A):
         self.a = a

    def new_func(self):
        return 2
```

I want to gradually replace `a.old_func` with `a.new_func. but first, I want to make sure that the new method always works the same way as the old one. So I've written a decorator to check that:

```
def refactor_factory(new_func):
    def refactor(old_func):
        def _wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            old_return_value = old_func(*args, **kwargs)
            new_return_value = new_func(**kwargs)

            if old_return_value != new_return_value:
                raise Exception("Mismatch")  # Add a complete log info

            return old_return_value

        return _wrapper

    return refactor
```

And I wanted to call it like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
    
    @refactor_factory(self.b.new_func)
    def old_func(self):
        return 2
    
    def new_func(self):
        return 2
```

The problem is that I can't pass the new_func to the decorator. I know I have access to `self` in the decorator, but when passing arguments, I don't have access to it, and therefore I can't pass its methods. Is there a way that I can achieve this?

p.s. I know that there are different designs to achieve what I want, like the one below, I just thought the first way was cleaner.

```
def refactor(old_func):
    def _wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        self = args[0]
        if isinstance(old_func, self.old_func):
            new_func = self.b.new_func
            
        old_return_value = old_func(*args, **kwargs)
        new_return_value = new_func(**kwargs)

        if old_return_value != new_return_value:
            raise Exception("Mismatch")  # Add a complete log info

        return old_return_value

    return _wrapper


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1

    @refactor_factory
    def old_func(self):
        return 2

    def new_func(self):
        return 2
```

Comment: Pass `A.new_func` as the argument, and call it as `new_func(self)`

Comment: Wow, you're right! I was thinking that I should pass the `new_func` as string, and then call it using `getattr` on self. but this was much easier!

Comment: Now I'm not even sure that this question is worth keeping, or if I should delete it. But Thank you very much anyways!

Comment: I think it's worth it, I'll post my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just pass `A.new_func`. In the wrapper, `self` will be one of the `*args`, so it will be passed along correctly.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
    
    @refactor_factory(A.new_func)
    def old_func(self):
        return 2
    
    def new_func(self):
        return 2
```